# Firestore cloud function create user trigger isn't supplying display name?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote an Firestore cloudfunction which creates a document in a user collection in my firestore database (following along with Fireship.io cloud functions video course).

The trigger seems to work properly (almost) except that for some reason, the displayName property of the user isn't getting passed into my user document.

Here is the code for my cloud function.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

export const onNewUser =functions.auth
.user()
.onCreate((user, context) => {

    const userRef = db.doc(`user/${user.uid}`);
    return userRef.set({
        name: user.displayName,
        createdAt: context.timestamp,
        email: user.email,
        verified: user.emailVerified,
        id: user.uid
    })
});
```

When I create a new user (I am using Angular `<ngx-auth-firebaseui>` to register and login a new user in my angular app) the new user document in firestore is created, but the supplied displayName isn't copied over to the user document collection. I confirmed this on the firebase console.

I suspected that somehow perhaps the displayName wasn't being saved in the authentication user object, but that's not the problem.  I can retrieve the displayName from the user object with AngularFireAuth.authState, it just doesn't get written to the user document with the onCreate trigger.

PS.  Is there a way to examine all the data for a user in the firebase console, including the displayName?  On the authentication pane, all I can see is the user "identified" (email address) and the UID.

**Edit**

The way the user is originally created is by including a sign-in and registration form provided by [ngx-auth-firebaseui](https://github.com/AnthonyNahas/ngx-auth-firebaseui) which handles all the implementation of user registration and authentication for Angular firebase apps.

The code in my authservice that allows me to retrieve the displayName from the authentication service once the user is registered is here:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { User } from './common/interfaces/user.model'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<User | null>;

  userId: string = "";
  userFirstName: string = "";
  loggedInState: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
  ) {

    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {

          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {

          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
    this.user$.subscribe(foo => {
      if (foo) { 
        this.userId = foo.uid;
        console.log(`uid: ${this.userId}`)
        if (foo.displayName) {this.userFirstName = foo.displayName.split(" ")[0]} else {this.userFirstName = foo.email};
        this.loggedInState=true;
      } else {
        this.userId = null;
        this.loggedInState=false;

      }
    })

  }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you're creating the user account on the client, and that it should have a displayName property

Comment: I still don't see where you create the user, but if you're using email+password sign-in this is expected behavior. Creating a user takes just the email+password in that case, and it's *that* first call that triggers the Cloud Function (at which point the user doesn't have a display name yet). Subsequent calls to set the display name, don't trigger Cloud Functions. The usual workaround is to pass email+password+displayname to a Cloud Function, which then creates the user account + document.Also see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/95 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48374886